# Reporting Services chart shows red X instead of graph

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have developed a report, which contains one matrix and one chart.  The chart shows a line graph using the data in the matrix.  When I preview the results, everything works fine.  The matrix contains data and the chart shows corresponding line.

It also works when I deploy the report to my local instance of the reporting services (running on my PC).

However, after I publish the report to our "real" reporting services box, only the matrix part works (it shows all the correct data), the chart is blank and shows either an empty rectangle with a little image in the corner (when run report from my PC) or a red x (when I run report while logged in locally on RS box).  This seems like some sort of setting or a security issue, but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected the issue was permissions.  I ended up granting "Read" rights to the users on the entire Reporting Services program directory and I can now see my charts displayed.  I will try to dig into it further to narrow down the directory where the permissions are needed, but at least I know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can relate to the folder that reporting services use to write temp files to.
Example location: ...\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\RSTempFiles

I think there is an issue where files(s) can get locked in use and be read only in here. When you run a report, reporting services tries to write in here and fails. Because it includes dll files, it cannot write and use the relevant one to show a graph.

I tried moving the temp files manually but gave up trying to get the files not in use. The easy way out is to restart reporting services and this cleans the folder out. This worked for me. Obviously this is not the best option as you don't want to interrupt the service. If this really wasn't an option it would be best to persist with cleaning the temp files folder.

Comment: this is a very late response, but I hope it will help some people out if they come across it